# Running Splashtop Streamer on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, desktop, vnc-server

I've just installed Splashtop Streamer on an Ubuntu 12.04 instance, and I'm not getting connectivity.

Splashtop do not support Ubuntu which is why I'm here.

When I run SRStreamer.pyc, the log says the following:

> Client is not authorized to connect to ServerClient is not authorized to connect to Server/user/lib/python/2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/**init**.py:57: GtkWarning: could not open display
>     warnings.warn(str(e), _gtk.Warning)
>
> (SRStreamer.pyc:2295): WARNING **: Command line 'dbus-launch --autolaunch=027300e486573dfe9fbf2c200000000d33 -- binary-syntax --close-stderr' exited with non-zeo status 1: Client is not authorized to connect to ServerClient is not authorized to connect to SeeverAutoLaunch error: X11 initialization failed.\n

I installed gtk2-engines-pixbuf, as this seemed a likely candidate, but alas no joy.

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 1):

Try logging in as root. Make sure xinit is installed and run startx.

```
    $ apt-get install xinit && startx
```

From the startx GUI, try the command

```
    $ python /opt/splashtop-streamer/SRStreamer.pyc
```